# How to install docker-engine using docker binary without internet connection

Tags: docker, installation, centos, binaryfiles

I have downloaded docker binary version 1.8.2 and copied that to my backup server (centos server) which doesn't have internet connectivity. I have marked this as executable and started the docker daemon as mentioned in [https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/][1]. But it doesn't seem to get installed as a docker service. For all the commands, I have to execute as sudo ./docker-1.8.2 {command}. Is there a way to install docker-engine as a service? Currently `sudo docker version` shows command not found. I'm a newbie to docker setup. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not [download the rpm package](http://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/Packages/) (there are also centos 6 packages), copy to USB stick and then to your server and simply install it with rpm command and that's it. That way you'd get the same installation as if you were to run yum.

Of course you may have some dependencies missing, but you could download all of these as well.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're downloading bare binaries on an enterprise linux, you're probably doing things in a very bad way.  Immediately, you're breaking updates and consistency, and leaving your system in a risky, messy state.

Try using yumdownloader --resolve to get the docker installable and anything it needs.

A better option may be to mirror the installation artifacts, and grab it from the local mirror, but that's beyond the scope if you don't do this already.